# Is there a way to use assigned variables without a constructor in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a fixed-size list which has 2 value had assigned in the same page. I want the first variable to be `headEmpty` second variable, `eyeEmpty`. I tried using constructor but I am changing those 2 values in the code so they should be dynamic at the same time.

Is there a way to use assigned variables without a constructor in Flutter?

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
@override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  String headEmpty = "assets/Empty.png";
  String eyeEmpty = "assets/Empty.png";
  List stackList = List.filled(2, 0);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
}
```

I tried:

```
_HomePageState(){ stackList[0]=headEmpty; stackList[1] = eyeEmpty }
```

This is where I change the variables:

```
onTap: () {
 setState(() {
 headEmpty = headButtonList[index].imageDirection;
 });
}
```

When I try to see the widget by `Image.assets(stackList[0])` It doesn't change anything.

Is there a way and is fixed-size list usage `true`?

Comment: Yes I tried that too it's not worked.

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  You talk about wanting to avoid using a constructor without explaining why.  What problem are you trying to solve?  Is your goal to make the `headEmpty = ...` assignment also be reflected by `stackList[0]`?  If so, that has nothing to do with constructors, and I instead would recommend that you do `List<String> stackList = ['assets/Empty.png', 'assets/Empty.png'];` and provide getters/setters for `headEmpty` and `eyeEmpty`.